# How do you get text from an image to the clipboard on macOS?

Tags: preview, image-editing

On iOS, copy/pasting text found in an image (e.g. a photo or screenshot) is as simple as double-tapping on the text in an image, and selecting "Copy".

How can I do this on macOS, for example, on a MacBook? (ideally, without any additional applications, but if necessary, preferably only light-weight, free ones)

Answer (score 2):

Here are three ways that don't require any additional software to be installed:

- Navigate to the image file in finder, and press <kbd>space</kbd> to open it with QuickLook, then text can be copied/pasted (credit to [@nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460411/how-do-you-get-text-from-an-image-to-the-clipboard-on-macos?noredirect=1#comment675498_460411))
- Double click on the image file to open it in Preview, hover the cursor over the text (the cursor will change from a cross to a text cursor), then you can drag the text cursor to select the text (credit to [@Gilby](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460411/how-do-you-get-text-from-an-image-to-the-clipboard-on-macos/460425?noredirect=1#comment675540_460411)).
- In Photos app, hover the cursor over the text in an image and drag the text cursor to select the text (credit to [@Thinkr](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460411/how-do-you-get-text-from-an-image-to-the-clipboard-on-macos#comment675599_460425))